# How to check mysql session/connection status with driver 8.0.XX C++ API

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector, mysql-8.0, mysql-x-devapi

In my C++ code, I am using MySQL driver 8.0.xx and using xdevapi because of the costly approach of establishing a connection to the database for each client request, I am using a pool of database connections.

mysqlx documentation [2.2.3 Connecting to a Single MySQL Server Using Connection Pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/connecting-connection-pool.html).

I Create a shared pointer from the client and using whenever it needs during the application life cycle.

**Create the Client Object:**

```cpp
mClient_ = std::make_shared<mysqlx::Client>(connectionString.str().c_str(), ClientOption::POOL_QUEUE_TIMEOUT, pPoolTimeout,
                                                    ClientOption::POOL_MAX_SIZE, pPoolSize);
```

**Getting Session and using:**

```cpp
mysqlx::Session session = mClient_->getSession();
mysqlx::RowResult res = session.sql(query.str().c_str()).execute();
```

it works fine, but if the application goes IDLE, pool sessions maybe drop, and the application is stuck, or in some cases it receives SIGSEGV, I can not find any way to check the connection status, for example before execution or after getting session?

I need some function like `session.isConnected()` or some routine to check the session before using it.

is there any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the session and execute right away or you get the session once and use it whenever you need?

Because the right pattern is to get a session, use it and destroy it, so it gets back to the pool. And this way, when you get a session, it is guaranteed it is a working one.